# How to clear history frames after done tracking in life streaming video?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

How to clear every frames that have been processed by tracking? because now in my application, it continues to increase the number of frames, consumes a lot of memory and makes my computer freeze.

Thank You.

**EDIT**

Start tracking with camshift algorithm with 3 method, update hue image, Hand tracker, and track hand.
1. convert image to hsv, get hue channel color, do histogram for hue channel
2. do back projection
3. do camshift-->meanshift algorithm

> ```
>     public void HandTracker(Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame, Rectangle currentrect)
>     {
>
>         hsv = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new Size(ImageFrame.Width, ImageFrame.Height), IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
>         hue = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new Size(ImageFrame.Width, ImageFrame.Height), IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
>         mask = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new Size(ImageFrame.Width, ImageFrame.Height), IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
>         backproject = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new Size(ImageFrame.Width, ImageFrame.Height), IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
>         histogram = new DenseHistogram(30, new RangeF(0, 180));
>
>         previoushand = currentrect;
>
>         UpdateHueImage(ImageFrame);
>
>         //show how many frame detected
>         frame = frame + 1;
>         label_1.Text = frame.ToString();
>
>         float vmax = 0;
>         float vmin = 0;
>         float scale = 0;
>         x = new IntPtr[1] { hue };
>
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvSetImageROI(hue, currentrect);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvSetImageROI(mask, currentrect);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCalcHist(x, histogram, false, mask);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvGetMinMaxHistValue(histogram, ref vmin, ref vmax, null, null);
>
>         if (vmax != 0)
>         {
>             scale = 255 / vmax;
>         }
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvConvertScale(histogram.MCvHistogram.bins, histogram.MCvHistogram.bins, scale, 0);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvResetImageROI(hue);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvResetImageROI(mask);
>
>         //if (ImageFrame != null) ImageFrame.Dispose();
>         Debug.WriteLine("hand tracker done!");
>
>     }
>
>
>     public Rectangle TrackHand(Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame)
>     {
>         MCvConnectedComp components = new MCvConnectedComp();
>
>         UpdateHueImage(ImageFrame);
>
>         //show how many frame detected
>         frame = frame + 1;
>         label_2.Text = frame.ToString();
>
>         IntPtr[] x = { hue };
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCalcBackProject(x, backproject, histogram);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvAnd(backproject, mask, backproject, IntPtr.Zero);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCamShift(backproject, previoushand, new MCvTermCriteria(10, 1), out components, out handcomp);
>
>         previoushand = components.rect;
>
>         ImageFrame.Draw(previoushand, new Bgr(Color.Black), 2);
>
>         Debug.WriteLine("Track hand done!");
>
>         return currenthand;
>     }
>
>
>     private void UpdateHueImage(Image<Bgr, Byte> currentrect)
>     {
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCvtColor(currentrect, hsv, COLOR_CONVERSION.CV_BGR2HSV);
>
>         int vmin = 65;
>         int vmax = 256;
>         int smin = 55;
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvInRangeS(hsv, new MCvScalar(0, smin, Math.Min(vmin, vmax), 0), 
>             new MCvScalar(180, 256, Math.Max(vmin, vmax), 0), 
>             mask);
>         Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvSplit(hsv, hue, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
>
>         Debug.WriteLine("UpdateHueImage done!");
>
>     }
> ```

That is my code for camshift tracking, I found that it's consume too much memory and my pc freeze after 800++ frame detected. How I delete cache ImageFrame that already processed?

Comment: You can more efficiently use a using statement such as using(Image<Gray,byte> myImage = new  Image<Gray,byte>(_capture.Queryframe().toBitmap())){.....} this will automatically call a dispose() method for the image however please update you question with the code that is causing problems so it can be more effectively addressed, thanks

Comment: I already update with my code, can you correct what I have to do for dispose and clear frame detected? @Chris

Answer (score 0):

call the `Dispose()` method when the images are already processed. This will release the unmanaged IplImage structure that is consuming the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The exactly what you need is implemented in:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions

check fast template matching sample, particle filter sample (hand tracking).
The class which is suitable for holding history is called History.